# Configuring reticulate to use conda environment

Tags: python, r, reticulate

I'm trying to get R's reticulate package to detect the Python interpreter in one of my conda-environments. Following several posts and questions, I've attempted to

- set the `RETICULATE_PYTHON` environment variable in .Rprofile (both in user as well as project directory)
- set `RETICULATE_PYTHON` in a `.Renviron` file
- use the provided helper functions `use_python()` and `use_condaenv()`,

all in vain. On start-up, the environment variable is correctly configured:

```
Sys.getenv("RETICULATE_PYTHON")
[1] "C:\\Users\\Othman\\anaconda3\\envs\\data_science\\python.exe"
```

but as soon as I run `py_config()`, it automatically sets it to the global (base) Python install:

```
r$> py_config()
python:         C:/Users/Othman/anaconda3/python.exe
libpython:      C:/Users/Othman/anaconda3/python39.dll
pythonhome:     C:/Users/Othman/anaconda3
version:        3.9.7 (default, Sep 16 2021, 16:59:28) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]
Architecture:   64bit
numpy:          C:/Users/Othman/anaconda3/Lib/site-packages/numpy
numpy_version:  1.20.3

NOTE: Python version was forced by RETICULATE_PYTHON

r$> Sys.getenv("RETICULATE_PYTHON")
[1] "C:\\Users\\Othman\\anaconda3\\python.exe"
```

Any idea what could be causing this?

Answer (score 3):

Ok, so after a few frustrating hours, I finally figured out the problem. If you use the improved `radian` console for R (available [here](https://github.com/randy3k/radian)), which is written in Python, it forces the reticulate to use the same Python runtime. Hopefully this helps save someone who (like me) glanced over the FAQ some time and frustration.

Comment: did simply installing radian fix the issue?  did you install it on your base python environment, or the environment you were trying to use?

Comment: @ThomasMatthew Yes, you have to install radian in the environment whose python interpreter you want to use, e.g. base reticulate will always use base python in radian.